# Principal value of 1/x- equivalence of two definitions

Tags: distribution-theory, mathematical-physics

As far as I know, the principal value of a non-summable function like $1/x$, denoted $\mathcal{P}(1/x)$, is a distribution that that acts on some smooth function $f$ in some test-function space and gives back the number:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}(1/x)\,\,f=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathcal{R}-[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx
\end{equation}

How would you prove rigorously that this is equivalent to:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}(1/x)\,\,f=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int\frac{x\,f(x)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\,dx
\end{equation}

Answer (score 5):

I am working on the same exercise. In a previous exercise I showed that
$$ \lim_{ \varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+ } \int_{|x| \geq \varepsilon} \frac{ f(x) }{x}dx = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) \ln(|x|) dx,$$
see [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436639/lim-varepsilon-rightarrow-0-int-x-geq-varepsilon-frac-varph?rq=1)

Now observe that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2 + \varepsilon^2} f(x) dx = f(x) \frac{1}{2} \ln(|x^2 + \varepsilon^2|)\big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) \frac{1}{2}\ln(|x^2 + \varepsilon^2|) dx$$
$$ = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) \frac{1}{2}\ln(|x^2 + \varepsilon^2|) dx$$

Then let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ to complete the proof.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to observe that both those expressions are the distributional derivative of (integration against) $\log|x|$.