# Why is $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}x \mathrm{d}x$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Isn't
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}x \mathrm{d}x=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}} \int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}x \mathrm{d}x+\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}x \mathrm{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{1}x \mathrm{d}x=0 ?$$

Comment: I presume your intention is that each of those three terms goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Look up Cauchy principle value. It's somewhat related to your issue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, $\frac 1 x$ isn't defined on $[-1,1]$ (because of what happens in $0$). You could get around this by considering it defined on $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$, but then you've got another problem, much more serious: the function is unbounded, and the concept of "Riemann integral" is defined *only* for bounded functions (and bounded intervals).

Finally, you might try to use the concept of "improper integral of the second kind". This doesn't work, either: $\int \limits _{-1} ^1 \frac 1 x \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _{-1} ^0 \frac 1 x \ \Bbb d x + \int \limits _0 ^1 \frac 1 x \ \Bbb d x = \infty - \infty$ which is indeterminate.

What you are trying to do is to give a meaning to that integral using the concept of ["principal value"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245211/principal-value-of-1-x-equivalence-of-two-definitions), in the framework of distribution theory. But this is clearly not the same as saying that your function is integrable with integral $0$.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better answer then this.

Answer (score 4):

I presume your intention is that $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ by way of a simple substitution, and then the middle integral "should be zero since the integrand is odd".

Unfortunately, $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x \neq 0$. The integrand is not defined at $0$, and $0$ is in the region of integration. This means that the integral is not defined either.

You can't really escape this problem. If you try to evaluate the integral as
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{-}}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
then you run into the problem that neither of your two new limits are convergent. For example,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\big(\ln{1}-\ln{\epsilon}\big) = -\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\ln{\epsilon},$$
and this last clearly diverges to infinity.